# User memory limit exceeded-large shape vector file in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am quite new to GEE. I am basically trying to get spectral indices for a set of vector points across Spain (plot located with latitude and longitude) covering the scale from 1985 to 2020.

I am trying to get them by using several sensors (i.e Sentinel, Landsat, MODIS,..) images overlapping the plot shapefiles. However, I can´t get the right code since I am always getting memory issues.

For this example, I have created 3 polygons trying to reduce the image size:

```
//geometry_1_peninsula
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon ([[[-18.33, 44.15], [-18.16, 26.51],[5.4, 26.98],[4.7, 42.74]]])

var geometry_1 = ee.Geometry.Polygon ([[[-9.297, 43.517],[3.886, 43.357],[-1.431, 36.103],[-9.561, 36.103]]])
var geometry_2 = ee.Geometry.Polygon ([[[1.118, 39.164],[3.842, 40.514],[4.458, 39.674],[1.557, 38.445]]])
var geometry_3 = ee.Geometry.Polygon ([[[-18.554, 29.187],[-13.259, 29.283],[-13.655, 27.485],[-18.379, 27.524]]])


//var filterAll =ee.Filter.inList("geometry_name",[geometry_1_p], [geometry_2_b],[geometry_3_c]);
//var all = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry.filter(filterAll)).geometry().disolve()

//image collection
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
.filterDate ("2020-01-01", "2020-12-30") 
.filterBounds(geometry_1) 
.sort("CLOUD_COVER")
print(S2);

//Reduce the collection
var extrema = S2.reduce(ee.Reducer.minMax());
print("1. extrema", extrema)

var median = S2.reduce(ee.Reducer.median());
print("3.median", median);


//vegetation and soil pixeles
function fieldpixel(image){
  var scl = image.select("SCL");
  var veg = scl.eq(4);
  var soil = scl.eq(5);
  var mask = (veg.neq(1)).or (soil.neq(1));
  
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}
//filter applied
var S2 = S2.map(fieldpixel);

//mask clouds
function maskS2clouds(image){
  var qa = image.select("QA60");
  
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
    
    return image.updateMask (mask);
}

// NDVI computation

var addNDVI = function(image){
  return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(["B8","B4"]));
}

//NDVI to image colection
var S2 = S2.map(addNDVI);
print(S2);


//NDVI time series
var evoNDVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
  S2,               //image collection
  geometry_1,             //region
  ee.Reducer.mean(), //Type of reducer to apply
  "nd",             //Band
  10);              //Scale

  
// plotting the NDVI
var plotNDVI1 = evoNDVI                     //Data
      .setChartType("LineChart")            //Type of plot
      .setSeriesNames (["SCL filter only"])
      .setOptions({                         //Plot customization
        interpolateNulls: true,
        lineWidth: 1,
        pointSize: 3,
        title: "NDVI annual evolution",
        hAxis: {title: "Date"},
        vAxis: {title: "NDVI"},
        series: {0: {color:"blue"}}
      });

print(plotNDVI1);

//cloud masking and plotting

var S2 = S2.map(maskS2clouds);

var plotNDVI2 = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
  S2,
  geometry_1,
  ee.Reducer.mean(),
  "nd",10)
  .setChartType("LineChart")
  .setSeriesNames(["After cloud filter"])
  .setOptions({
    interpolateNulls: true,
    lineWidth: 1,
    pointSize: 3,
    title: "NDVI annual evolution",
    hAxis: {title: "Date"},
    vAxis: {title: "NDVI"},
    series: {0: {color:"red"}}
      });

print(plotNDVI2);


//NDVI map

var NDVI = S2.select(["nd"]);
var NDVImed = NDVI.median();
var pal = ["#d73027","#f46d43", "#fdae61", "#fee08b", "#d9ef8b", "#a6d96a"];

Map.addLayer(
  NDVImed.clip(geometry_1),     //clip map to plot borders)
  {min:0.2, max:0.6, palette: pal}, //specify color palette
  "NDVI")                       //Layer name

////geometry_2_baleares

//image collection
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
.filterDate ("2020-01-01", "2020-12-30") 
.filterBounds(geometry_1) 
.sort("CLOUD_COVER")
print(S2);

//Reduce the collection
var extrema = S2.reduce(ee.Reducer.minMax());
print("1. extrema", extrema)

var median = S2.reduce(ee.Reducer.median());
print("3.median", median);


//vegetation and soil pixeles
function fieldpixel(image){
  var scl = image.select("SCL");
  var veg = scl.eq(4);
  var soil = scl.eq(5);
  var mask = (veg.neq(1)).or (soil.neq(1));
  
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}
//filter applied
var S2 = S2.map(fieldpixel);

//mask clouds
function maskS2clouds(image){
  var qa = image.select("QA60");
  
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
    
    return image.updateMask (mask);
}

// NDVI computation

var addNDVI = function(image){
  return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(["B8","B4"]));
}

//NDVI to image colection
var S2 = S2.map(addNDVI);
print(S2);


//NDVI time series
var evoNDVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
  S2,               //image collection
  geometry_2,             //region
  ee.Reducer.mean(), //Type of reducer to apply
  "nd",             //Band
  10);              //Scale

  
// plotting the NDVI
var plotNDVI1 = evoNDVI                     //Data
      .setChartType("LineChart")            //Type of plot
      .setSeriesNames (["SCL filter only"])
      .setOptions({                         //Plot customization
        interpolateNulls: true,
        lineWidth: 1,
        pointSize: 3,
        title: "NDVI annual evolution",
        hAxis: {title: "Date"},
        vAxis: {title: "NDVI"},
        series: {0: {color:"blue"}}
      });

print(plotNDVI1);

//cloud masking and plotting

var S2 = S2.map(maskS2clouds);

var plotNDVI2 = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
  S2,
  geometry_2,
  ee.Reducer.mean(),
  "nd",10)
  .setChartType("LineChart")
  .setSeriesNames(["After cloud filter"])
  .setOptions({
    interpolateNulls: true,
    lineWidth: 1,
    pointSize: 3,
    title: "NDVI annual evolution",
    hAxis: {title: "Date"},
    vAxis: {title: "NDVI"},
    series: {0: {color:"red"}}
      });

print(plotNDVI2);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: NDVI2,
  description: "NDVI_peninsula",
  fileFormat: "CSV"
})


//NDVI map

var NDVI = S2.select(["nd"]);
var NDVImed = NDVI.median();
var pal = ["#d73027","#f46d43", "#fdae61", "#fee08b", "#d9ef8b", "#a6d96a"];

Map.addLayer(
  NDVImed.clip(geometry_2),     //clip map to plot borders)
  {min:0.2, max:0.6, palette: pal}, //specify color palette
  "NDVI")                       //Layer name

///geometry_3_canarias

//image collection
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
.filterDate ("2020-01-01", "2020-12-30") 
.filterBounds(geometry_3) 
.sort("CLOUD_COVER")
print(S2);

//Reduce the collection
var extrema = S2.reduce(ee.Reducer.minMax());
print("1. extrema", extrema)

var median = S2.reduce(ee.Reducer.median());
print("3.median", median);


//vegetation and soil pixeles
function fieldpixel(image){
  var scl = image.select("SCL");
  var veg = scl.eq(4);
  var soil = scl.eq(5);
  var mask = (veg.neq(1)).or (soil.neq(1));
  
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}
//filter applied
var S2 = S2.map(fieldpixel);

//mask clouds
function maskS2clouds(image){
  var qa = image.select("QA60");
  
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
    
    return image.updateMask (mask);
}

// NDVI computation

var addNDVI = function(image){
  return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(["B8","B4"]));
}

//NDVI to image colection
var S2 = S2.map(addNDVI);
print(S2);


//NDVI time series
var evoNDVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
  S2,               //image collection
  geometry_3,             //region
  ee.Reducer.mean(), //Type of reducer to apply
  "nd",             //Band
  10);              //Scale

  
// plotting the NDVI
var plotNDVI1 = evoNDVI                     //Data
      .setChartType("LineChart")            //Type of plot
      .setSeriesNames (["SCL filter only"])
      .setOptions({                         //Plot customization
        interpolateNulls: true,
        lineWidth: 1,
        pointSize: 3,
        title: "NDVI annual evolution",
        hAxis: {title: "Date"},
        vAxis: {title: "NDVI"},
        series: {0: {color:"blue"}}
      });

print(plotNDVI1);

//cloud masking and plotting

var S2 = S2.map(maskS2clouds);

var plotNDVI2 = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
  S2,
  geometry_3,
  ee.Reducer.mean(),
  "nd",10)
  .setChartType("LineChart")
  .setSeriesNames(["After cloud filter"])
  .setOptions({
    interpolateNulls: true,
    lineWidth: 1,
    pointSize: 3,
    title: "NDVI annual evolution",
    hAxis: {title: "Date"},
    vAxis: {title: "NDVI"},
    series: {0: {color:"red"}}
      });

print(plotNDVI2);


//NDVI map

var NDVI = S2.select(["nd"]);
var NDVImed = NDVI.median();
var pal = ["#d73027","#f46d43", "#fdae61", "#fee08b", "#d9ef8b", "#a6d96a"];

Map.addLayer(
  NDVImed.clip(geometry_1),     //clip map to plot borders)
  {min:0.2, max:0.6, palette: pal}, //specify color palette
  "NDVI")                       //Layer name
```

Here, I can get only one plot from the smallest geometry (geometry_2 but then I cannot export it as CSV or TIFF file, I get this error:

(NDVI2 is not defined)

[image: screenshot]

and this one for geometry_1 and geometry_3

> ImageCollection (Error) Collection query aborted after accumulating
> over 5000 elements.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post the same question again, rather edit the original question with the new/improved info: [User memory limit exceeded-large vectori file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/436754/user-memory-limit-exceeded-large-vectori-file)

Comment: Making a habit of deleting and reposting Questions (in either order) will attract the attention of the automated anti-spam defenses of StackExchange.

Comment: sorry, I am new in this platform and thought that the first post was not approved so that I created a second one! I´d appreciate an answer in regards to my errors issue. Thanks

Comment: I can only get the ndvi plot for the geometry_2 (smallest one) however I cannot export the values as CSV file, getting the error: (NDVI is not defined)

Answer (score 1):

I'm just giving some general advices without reviewing the entire code that, at first glance, could probably be improved in different parts.
I won't go into what is better to achieve your goals, but there are few things I noticed that maybe could help you:

- for what concerns the second example, it works, there's only a minor error, you probably have to substitute `.filterBounds(geometry_1)` with `.filterBounds(geometry_2)`. The image and the charts are correctly generated.
- about the third example, you should probably change `Map.addLayer( NDVImed.clip(geometry_1)` with `Map.addLayer( NDVImed.clip(geometry_3)`; here the image is generated but the charts aren't. I noticed that the number of elements of the ImageCollection (2101) is more than double than those ones in the second example (1017). You should try to find the reason of this difference, because the datasets should be exactey the same. Apparently, it's a huge number of images, and this is probably one of the reasons why you get error messages, also in exemple 1 (whole Spain);
- about the error `NDVI2 is not defined` there's simply no variable named like that;
- to export the charts, if you don't have any particular needs, you can simply click on the button on the right of the charts and then on "Download CSV":
  [image]

You say that you are analyzing data from 1985 to 2020, but the only time filter I could find in the code is for 2020. And as a general advise, you could maybe use better shaped geometries, for better performances.